# Get Period of subscription in Android Google Play Billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

How could I get the period of current user subscription? I have Pro subscription with 2 available period options: monthly and annual. Now I want to show user his current subscription's period, but I found

{

"orderId": "GPA.3330-5508-5196-85609",

"packageName": "mypackage",

"productId": "pro_android_v1",

"purchaseTime": 1664115448930,

"purchaseState": 0,

"purchaseToken": "purchase token",

"obfuscatedAccountId": "some",

"quantity": 1,

"autoRenewing": true,

"acknowledged": true

}